# Индексаторы C#, значения вывода, при различных индексах

Tags: c#

я понимаю для чего служат индексаторы, но вот столкнулся с заданием, и просто не понимаю, как правильно вызвать и как передать...
имеется перечисление(enum):

```
 public enum Frenquency
    {
        Wekly, Monthly, Yearly
    }
```

Имеется класс с индексатором(не буду выкладывать весь, выложу индексатор):

```
public bool this[Frenquency index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (Frenquency == index)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Создаю объект класса, где данный индексатор, далее по заданию требуется, цитата:

> Вывести значения индексатора для значений индекса
>   Frequency.Weekly, Frequency.Monthly и Frequency.Yearly.

И тут у меня вопрос, как мне это просто напросто сделать, я действительно не понимаю.. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение моей проблемы, было найдено методом "тыка", за что стыдно, однако найдено:

```
Magazine mag = new Magazine();//этой мой класс с индексатором имеется конструктор поумолчанию
Console.WriteLine(mag[(Frenquency)2]);
```

Comment: @Aqua тем более, что это просто строчка кода из вопроса )

Comment: @Igor,здрастье, какая строчка из кода?
Проблема была в том, что я не понимал, как сослаться на созданный индексатор.... Вот и нашёл проблему..... Исправил и в вопросе и дал ответ!

Comment: В вопросе, ответов быть не должно. Правьте вопрос, что бы в ВОПРОСЕ был только ВОПРОС с дополнениями (как и было). А в ответ, где вы нашли решение вашей проблемы, опишите почему так и т.д.

Comment: + ответ, который дал @Igor нагляднее и правильнее демонстрирует решение вашей проблемы. Т.к. upcast тут незачем.

Comment: @Aqua, до моего ответа, Igor, дал совершенно не верный ответ и далекий от моего вопроса.....

Comment: @Valera Мой ответ и сейчас далек от Вашего вопроса, так как Вы опять удалили описание того, что должен делать/возвращать индексатор.

Comment: @Igor, в  вопросе составлен правильный индексатор(согласно заданию), следовательно возвращает он true/flase. Всем спасибо, ответ есть. Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: `я понимаю для чего служат индексаторы` ну в таком случае я думаю стоило бы почитать и как пользоваться ими. Разве я не прав? Вопрос не несет никакой пользы для читателей. Вы сами задали вопрос, сами ответели...

Comment: @nick_n_a ой да, забыл, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

"значения индексатора" - ?

```
public class Magazine {
  public Frenquency Frenquency { get; set; }

  public bool this[Frenquency index]
  {
    get { return Frenquency == index; }
  }
}

Magazine mag = new Magazine();
Console.WriteLine(mag[Frenquency.Wekly]);    // true
Console.WriteLine(mag[Frenquency.Monthly]);  // false
Console.WriteLine(mag[Frenquency.Yearly]);   // false
```